# How do I write a mongoDB aggregate query for the below shown documents and get the result as shown below?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am new to mongoDB. Tried a lot of things but none worked.
I have documents with fields as shown below(and many other fields, posting just relevant ones).

| APP OWNER | TECHNOLOGY | ENVIRONMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| appowner1 | Neptune | PROD |
| appowner2 | RDS | NONPROD |
| appowner3 | DynamoDB | PROD |
| appowner4 | Redshift | NONPROD |
| appowner5 | Migration | PROD |
| appowner6 | DocumentDB | NONPROD |
| appowner7 | Elastic | PROD |
| appowner8 | Neptune | NONPROD |
| appowner9 | RDS | PROD |
| appowner10 | DynamoDB | NONPROD |
| appowner11 | Redshift | PROD |
| appowner12 | Migration | NONPROD |
| appowner13 | DocumentDB | PROD |
| appowner14 | Elastic | NONPROD |

How to write a mongoDB aggregate query to get the following output?

| TECHNOLOGY | PROD | NON PROD | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Neptune | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| RDS | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| DynamoDB | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Redshift | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Migration | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| DocumentDB | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Elastic | 2 | 2 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$technology",
      "PROD": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$environment",
                "PROD"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "NONPROD": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$environment",
                "NONPROD"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "TOTAL": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "technology": "$_id",
      "TOTAL": 1,
      "PROD": 1,
      "NONPROD": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Here, we group by technology field and calculate the `PROD`, `NONPROD` and `TOTAL` values. Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QwFuZHz4IsM).

Or as suggested in the comments by nimrod serok. You can try this, cleaner way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$technology",
      "PROD": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$environment",
                "PROD"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "TOTAL": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "technology": "$_id",
      "TOTAL": 1,
      "PROD": 1,
      "NONPROD": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$TOTAL",
          "$PROD"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vtc-y-nQBu-).

Comment: I would consider to reduce some effort like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vtc-y-nQBu-)

Comment: Yeah absolutely. That's cleaner.

Comment: Hi Charchit, That worked pretty well and I understood the approach as well.

Comment: Thanks @nimrodserok. That's pretty clean.